# Cannot convert from "string" to "int". Unity, trying to add a highscore using player.position.z

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Im trying to add a highscore based on the players "Z" position.**

**I can´t understand whats wrong.**

```
void Start()
{

    highScore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0).ToString();

}

void UpdateScore()
{
    string number = player.position.z.ToString();

    highScore.text = score.text.ToString();

    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", number); //here is where i get the error
}
```

Comment: Maybe there's nothing wrong at all?  Why don't you tell us what behavior of the system leads you to believe there's a problem?

Comment: `number` is defined as a string. define it as `int` and remove the `.ToString()`

Comment: yeah but then i get tanother error saying that cannot implicitly convert float to int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you convert the position (float) to a string, then try to convert the string to an int ?

Simply round / floor / ceil the z position of your player :

```
int number = Mathf.RoundToInt( player.position.z ) ;

highScore.text = score.text.ToString();

PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", number);
```

Converting to a string and parsing is not very resources-friendly, especially if you do it every frame.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old but actually:

Why not just keep it as `float` instead:

```
private float currentScore;

void Start()
{
    currentScore = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore", 0);
    highScore.text = currentScore.ToString("F0");
}

void UpdateScore()
{
    currentScore = player.position.z;

    highScore.text = currentScore.ToString("F0");

    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("HighScore", currentScore );
}
```